# How to start two instances of the same app with different static values?

Tags: c++, qt, instance

**Problem**: I want to run my application with the different arguments, for example `app.exe -param1` and a little bit later I need to start `app.exe -param2`. Parameters comes from arguments. Arguments I need to place to **global static value**, to be able to get it at any time from any where in code.

How to do that?

I have tried:

```
static QString gMyValues;
```

then from `main.cpp` I do something:

```
::gMyValues = QString( argv[ argc - 1 ] );
```

and then from any class I'm trying to get:

```
::gMyValues;
```

but no luck, gMyValues empty, but at the begging it was with arg value...

PS. Let it be only `int`'s params.

Thanks!

Comment: There is a Qt way to get the arguments: http://doc.qt.nokia.com/latest/qcoreapplication.html#arguments

Answer (score 4, accepted):

My guess is you have more than one definition of the variable. Do you have this line in a header file?

```
static QString gMyValues;
```

If so, each and every source file that includes it will have its own copy of `gMyValues`. And only the one in `main.cpp` will be filled with correct value.

You should declare it in the header file like this:

```
extern QString gMyValues;
```

And define it in `main.cpp`:

```
QString gMyValues;
```

The `static` keyword in global level doesn't mean what you think it does. It means private linkage: http://thesmithfam.org/blog/2010/06/12/the-many-meanings-of-the-c-static-keyword/